# Is there a way in a Helm chart to take secrets stored as text strings and write them out to a file while installing the chart?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I am working on my first project using AWS EKS. My company has their own proprietary workflow for deploying apps to EKS which includes the requirement to use Helm.
I need to take terraform and k8s yaml code provided by a vendor to stand up their app, and convert it to fit my company's proprietary standards. One of those standards requires that secrets not be stored with the code. I have to store secrets as text strings in a specific secrets.yaml file, which is then stored in a secure location and brought into the chart on the fly while it's installing it.

That's the background, now here's the question...
The vendor provided app is designed to ingest credentials in the form of a text file. This text file is expected to be in with the code, which I can't do.
Is there a way to embed a script or something within my Helm chart which can take these credentials which I have stored in the secrets file as a text string, and output to a temporary text file while the chart is being installed so that the file exists that the app needs?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `secrets.yaml` is added as a Kubernetes Secret in your environment?

What you can do is add the secret as a file in your app.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: secret-volume-example
spec:
  containers:
  - name: provider-app
    image: provider-app
    volumeMounts:
    - name: foo
      mountPath: "/path/to/provider/expected/location"
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: foo
    secret:
      secretName: mysecret
```

Comment: I can't do that. Our company policy does not allow us to store secrets with our code. That's the problem. The app requires that I have the secret (credentials) in a separate dedicated text file in with the code, but my company policy dictates that all secrets be in the form of text strings within this particular secrets.yaml file.

I need to try to come up with a way to take the strings from secrets.yaml and write them out to a text file during install so that the file the app needs is there without having it stored with the code..

Comment: How are the secrets.yaml injected into your chart? How exactly are they made available?

Comment: I don't know the specifics of what happens under the covers, but we have to use pre-built jobs in Jenkins to deploy our Helm charts. The secrets file is stored in Jenkins as a credential and somehow they add it into the chart before deploying it.

Comment: How is it made available to the chart? Are there variables set in the chart?

Comment: Because if variables are set and you can add them as environment variables to your app, you could create an Init container that reads those environment variables and writes them to a file.

Comment: The original intent was to have the info in a simple text file in the chart and then the location of that file would be passed to the template like so...

values.yaml...
db_creds_file: "<path to text file>"

template...
data:
  config_secrets: {{ .Values.db_creds_file }}

What I need is a way to pull the strings from secrets.yaml and write them out to a file while the chart is being installed so that it is available when the above code looks for it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to enter the code in a readable layout but it's cramming it all together in a single run on when I submit it.

Comment: Are the secrets.yaml secrets made available as Values in your chart? e.g. could you do `{{ .Values.secrets.some_secret }}`?

Comment: Also backticks: ` really help when formatting code in stackoverflow. You can use a line of code wrapped in single backticks for an inline line of code like the comment above or a couple of lines of code wrapped in triple backticks for larger code snippets.

Comment: Yes they are made available as Values in the chart. My issue is not accessing the Values from secrets.yaml, it is that I need these values in a text file that is not allowed to exist before the chart is installed.

I am also working with the vendor in parallel to see if they can change their app so that I can simply pass these as string Values, but right now it expects to find this file containing them.

Comment: And are you allowed to create Kubernetes Secrets based on the values?

Comment: I've tried use triple ticks, padding 4 spaces and using </br> for line breaks and everything I put in here keeps coming out as a single run on line of text. I don't know what I'm going wrong, but it's making it very difficult to show anything...

Comment: I believe that's what they're doing. Again, I'm pretty green here and trying to figure this out as I go so please forgive my ignorance... ***CODE*** apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ include "starters.fullname" . }}-cloud-cm-secrets
data:
  config_secrets: {{ .Values.db_creds_file }} ***END CODE***

Comment: Apparently using 3 asterisks changes text to bold and italic...

Comment: If they are creating secrets with the secrets.yaml you can use the above solution. Just make sure you pass the correct name of the secret to the volume. The data in the secret will then be loaded in to the volume at the specified mountPath. If some processing of the file needs to be done, you can run an init container that read the file, modifies the file and writes it to a new location (can't be the secret mountPath as it is read-only).

Comment: Sorry Blokje5, I guess I'm just not understanding the suggestion. Perhaps it's just over my head at this very early point in my k8s/Helm learning process.

Thanks for taking the time to try to help though!

Comment: Sorry that did not help. I can link to some documentation that might help though: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/ for init containers. secrets: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/. volumes: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/. Those should help you get started in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the effort. For now I have placed the info in the file where the vendor expects to find it so that I can get past this. I'll need to circle back and change that before I can promote beyond dev.